# Zip function not showing complete list of scraped data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have written a crawler to extract prices, name and reviews from a site . But when I am clubbing them together, only 9 results are being shown out of 30 . Dont know where is the problem. Also I need to add next page links, where shud i do that.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest, time, re
import time
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import sys;
reload(sys);
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf8")


class Agoda(CrawlSpider):
name = 'agoda'
allowed_domains = ["agoda.com"]
start_urls = ["http://www.agoda.com"] 
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.agoda.com")
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_area_promo_HomeSearchBox1_TextSearch1_searchText").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_area_promo_HomeSearchBox1_TextSearch1_searchText").send_keys("Mumbai")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[contains(@id,'ddlCheckInDay')]")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[contains(.,'Mon 09')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_area_promo_HomeSearchBox1_SearchButton").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentMain_rptAB1936_ctl01_rptSearchResultAB1936_ctl01_lnkResult1936" or "ctl00_ContentMain_rptSearchResult_ctl01_lnkResult" or "ctl00_ContentMain_rptSearchResult_ctl01_lnkResult").click()
#driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentMain_rptSearchResult_ctl01_lnkResult").click()
time.sleep(40);
#print driver.page_source
TotalResults = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='blue ssr_search_text']")
print TotalResults.text

html_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source) 


names = soup("a", {"class":"hot_name"})



prices = soup("span", {"class":"fontxlargeb purple"})

reviews = soup("a", {"class":"fontlargeb"})  

hotel_names = [name[1].get_text() for name in enumerate(names)] #or [name[1].get_text() for name in enumerate(names)]
prices = [price[1].get_text() for price in enumerate(prices)] 
reviews = [review[1].get_text() for review in enumerate(reviews)] #[price[1].get_text() for price in enumerate(prices)]

name_price_list = zip(hotel_names, prices, reviews)

for name, price, review in name_price_list:
    print name, price, review
```

Comment: `zip` shortens the returned data to the length of shortest iterable.

Comment: So how should I get the complete result or there is some other alternative to zip() to associate attributes.

Comment: Use [`itertools.izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) from itertools

> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.
>   If the iterables are of uneven length, missing values are filled-in
>   with fillvalue. Iteration continues until the longest iterable is
>   exhausted

example:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l2 = ['a','b','c']
>>> l1 = [1, 2]
>>> list(itertools.izip_longest(l1, l2))
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (None, 'c')]
```

Comment: Actually I have 3 attributes. When I am doing itertools.izip_longest(name, price, review) , I am getting complete results for name and prices but not for reviews in the code.

Comment: @Tarun and on site all 3 lists have all items? maybe not all 'items' have reviews and all have price and name...

Comment: There was a xpath issue. Thank you so much